# Maintaining Factor Order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, levels

I am attempting to combine two data sets and chart types into a single ggplot.  I want to plot the main data in a line/connected dot plot (two observations of the same kind within each of 5 categories), and a set of n random observations in a 6th category as a dot plot, geom_point().

This issue I am having is that the  order of the categories which I am trying to specify using factor levels is not maintained after adding the second geom_point() with the supplemental data.  Example plots are below.

Anyone know how to force the order of the categories as specified by the factor levels?

```
main_data <- data.frame(variable = c(rep("min", 5), rep("max", 5)),
             category = c("apples", "bananas", "peaches", "pears", "melons"),
             value = c(seq(0.2, 0.28, by = 0.02), seq(0.8, 0.56, by = -0.06)))

supplemental_data <- data.frame(variable = rep("random_observation", 10), category = rep("chicken", 10), value = runif(10, 0, 1))

all_data <- rbind(main_data, supplemental_data) %>% 
            mutate(category = factor(category, levels = c("bananas", 
                                                          "peaches", 
                                                          "apples", 
                                                          "melons", 
                                                          "pears", 
                                                          "chicken")))


ggplot() +
geom_line(data = all_data %>% filter(variable != "random_observation"), aes(x = category, y = value, group = variable, colour=variable), size = 1) +
geom_point(data = all_data %>% filter(variable != "random_observation"), aes(x = category, y = value, group = variable, colour=variable)) +
geom_point(data = all_data %>% filter(variable == "random_observation"), aes(x = category, y = value, group = variable), colour = "dark red") +
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
scale_colour_manual(values = c("Red", "Blue")) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#C0C0C0", colour = "000000"),
      legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Restart your R session new and use the code you provided. I can' t reproduce your issue!

Comment: Agree with TarJae. Can't reproduce your issue using `ggplot2 ‘3.4.4’`.

Comment: Re-Loaded R and I get the same result.  Anyone else?  the order of x axis categories come out the same as the order the factor levels are specified?

Comment: Could you check your ggplot2 Version, i.e. `packageVersion("ggplot2")`? Perhaps that's the reason why we can't reproduce. As a reference: I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwLY1.png when running your code using ggplot2 3.4.4.

Comment: ... a workaround might be to force the order by setting the limits of the scale, i.e. `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = c("bananas", "peaches", "apples", "melons", "pears", "chicken"))`.

Comment: I am on ggplot2 '3.3.5'.   Workaround is good enough for now, thanks!  I'll try a newer version of ggplot2 in a different environment, I think you're right that is probably the issue.